# Moving a UIView with subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview

I'd like to have a view (UIView) with two `UIImageView` subviews,
and then move the two images (simultaneously) around the screen.

In scenario 1, I create a `UIView` with the dimensions of the screen, and leave it fixed,
and then move the center point of the two subviews around. In scenario 2, I create
a `UIView` the size of the two images, and move the `UIView` centre point around the screen.

I would have thought the end result would be the same, but it's not.
Why not?

scenario 1:

```
UIView mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIImageView firstImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:muchSmallerRect];
UIImageView secondImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:muchSmallerRect];
[mainView addSubview:firstImage];
[mainView addSubview:secondImage];
firstImage.center = someSpecificPoint;
secondImage.center = someSpecificPoint;
```

scenario 2:

```
UIView mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:muchSmallerRect];
UIImageView firstImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:muchSmallerRect];
UIImageView secondImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:muchSmallerRect];
[mainView addSubview:firstImage];
[mainView addSubview:secondImage];
mainView.center = someSpecificPoint;
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about "the difference in end results"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about two different coordinate systems. `mainView.center` is expressed in the coordinate system of the view that contains `mainView`, whereas `firstView.center` and `secondView.center` are in terms of the coordinate system of `mainView`. You can certainly move `firstView` and `secondView` together by moving the view that contains them, but you need to translate between those two coordinate systems if you want to get the same result that you get by moving the two views themselves.

Comment: I had thought that because `muchSmallerRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0);` and all views (mainView and the two subview UIIMageViews) were the same size, the differing coordinate systems would line up. Obviously you are correct, as the end results vary wildly. Is this corrected by using `convertPoint:fromView:` ?